# capturing all form elements values in a single string

Tags: javascript

I have used the following javascript function to capture the values entered for each element in a form.Once user clicks on submit button,the values entered by user for each control must be displayed.
The code works well for all controls except radiobuttons.
Can anyone suggest me how to do it?

```
function DisplayFormValues(){
            var str = '';
            var elem = document.getElementById('form1').elements;
            for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
            {

                str += "<b>Name:</b>" + elem[i].name + "\n";
                str += "<b>Value:</b><i>" + elem[i].value + "\n";
                str += "<BR>";
            } 
            document.getElementById('lblValues').innerHTML = str;
        }
```

Comment: For each named radio button group, you have to locate the one that's checked and use its value.

Comment: yes that is true but I am not aware of the implementation of it in the present code.

Answer (score 1):

Values of radio buttons and checkboxes are not easy to get because they share the same name in the DOM. You have to loop through each of these elements and check which among its children are checked.

So, you need to expand your loop. One way of doing this is:

```
function DisplayFormValues(){
    var theform = document.form1;
    var a = ['input', 'textarea', 'select'];
    var echo = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        var tag = a[i];
        var els = theform.getElementsByTagName(tag);
        for (var j = 0; j<els.length; j++) {
            el = els[j]; // the element
            if ((tag == 'input' && (el.type == 'text' || el.type == 'password')) || tag == 'select') {
                echo += '<strong>' + el.name + '</strong>: ' + el.value + '<br />';
            } else if ((tag == 'checkbox' || tag == 'radio') && el.checked) { // the element is checked!
                echo += '<strong>' + el.name + '</strong>: ' + el.value + '<br />';
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('lblValues').innerHTML = echo;
}
```